# Extract pixels from NDVI in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-10.1, envi, ndvi, feature-extraction, extract-by-mask

I have a NDVI that I created from a Landsat 5 image. Is there a way to extract all the pixels above a certain threshold and save it as a shapefile? I am trying to create a vegetation mask of sorts to filter out areas in a city that have vegetation, leaving only the structures.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest option would be the use of [Raster Calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000z7000000.htm) with a [conditional statement](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000008000000.htm).
Your statement may look something like the following with 'threshold' replaced with whatever value you like.  The resulting raster will give you pixels with value=1 where values are greater than threshold, and NoData where values are less than threshold.

```
Con("NDVI_img" >= threshold, 1, "")
```

You could also do something like the following, which will result in all values greater than threshold retaining original values, where cells less than threshold have NoData.

```
Con("NDVI_img" >= threshold, "NDVI_img", "")
```

Comment: then you use "feature to raster" and you have your shapefile

Answer (score 0):

By adding more conditions in the syntax of conditional statement as @Barbarossa nicely explained the answer of what your requirement is, a more evaluation threshold can be added by adding a multiple conditions in this statement. I was to assign the some constant values like 0.99 where NDVI < 0.20, 0.97 where NDVI > 0.5 and between this threshold i had to give another derivative formula in it and I had accomplished it with multiple conditional statement [conditional evaluation with Con in ArcGIS raster calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000008000000.htm) in ArcGIS raster calculator, a very nice tool.

> Con(NDVI < 0.20, 0.97, Con( (NDVI >= 0.2)  & (NDVI <= 0.50), 0.004*((NDVI -
>    0.20)/(0.50-0.20)) ^ 2 + 0.986, 0.99 ) )

If anyone knows about the free tool like in QGIS, or GRASS using map calculator tool. share it how to do it.