# create a vegetation mask using Landsat 7

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, ndvi, landsat-7

I'm working on a very large study area. The aim is to create a vegetation mask representing only pines. I'm using Landsat 7 images. Since the recordings were made in the winter it's pretty easy to distinguish the conifers from the rest, because everything else is covered with snow.

Unfortunately I do not get a satisfactory result. What is the best methodology to get good results? I've tried to use a NDVI. Unfortunately, the results are bad.

I have also tried to use a tasseled cap transformation. Unfortunately, I have no experience using TC, so I'm not sure how to interpret/use the results.

I am using Erdas Imagine and ArcGIS.

Do you have any tips on how I can solve the problem?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what "bad" results are?  Thanks.

Comment: bad means, that I can not clearly see where pines are located. the values ​​do not tell so much and are all positive...

Answer (score 1):

The task that you are describing is called image classification.  There are numerous ways to classify an image--from very basic thresholding to more advanced supervised classification approaches.  Image classification using multispectral data like Landsat requires basic radiometric correction, often accomplished using Dark Object Subtraction. [Song et al. (2001)](http://www.unc.edu/courses/2008spring/geog/577/001/www/Song01_RSE.pdf) wrote a seminal paper to help answer 1) when atmospheric correction is necessary and 2) what methods to use.  There is an old, but useful video describing the process [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ED3jnYod6w).  I also suspect you are experiencing the ETM+ data gap issue, which may be influencing your results.  There are numerous methods to address this and a good place to start is [NASA](http://landsat.usgs.gov/using_Landsat_7_data.php).

There is a good description of how to perform image thresholding using NDVI data in ArcGIS available [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/75162/8104).  Maximum Likelihood classification is a common supervised approach and a good tutorial for Erdas can be found [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttjHpjJ7dV0).

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I know the process of supervised classification. I just wanted to know what the best method is to classify all the tiles and if I can do that with an index? The problem is that there are a lot of scenes for my (large) area of interest....

Comment: It is typically best to use individual bands (e.g. R,G,B,NIR) over a single index with a supervised classification.  However, it is often helpful to include an index in with the individual bands during the classification.